# c# Async curl request - how do I access the response?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, jira, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to convert a curl request example from an API for Jira into a C# request.

This is the original Curl Request example that JIRA provides:

```
curl \
   -D- \
   -u charlie:charlie \
   -X GET \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=charlie
```

Which I've translated into the below code for JIRA:

However the response lines don't work - because I've cobbled together a few examples and got a bit stuck!

```
var myTask = curlRequestAsync(); // call your method which will return control once it hits await

string result = myTask.Result();
// .Result isn't defined - but I'm not sure how to access the response from my request!
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm really stuck!

Full example:

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var myTask = curlRequestAsync(); // call your method which will return control once it hits await

        string result = myTask.Result();
        // wait for the task to complete to continue

    }

    protected async System.Threading.Tasks.Task curlRequestAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "http://myurl.co.uk/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=bob"))
                {
                    var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"));
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

                    var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error.InnerText = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably should use the `var result = await curlRequestAsync();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should return `Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>`

```
protected async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> curlRequestAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "http://myurl.co.uk/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=bob"))
            {
                var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"));
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

                var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         error.InnerText = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

after that you could access response of your task:

```
var myTask = curlRequestAsync();

var result = myTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: I'd avoid calling .Result. Better to call GetAwaiter.GetResult() then you get the original exception and not an Aggregate.

Comment: @RalphWillgoss  yes, you are right. And the code is twice "result" is quite ugly. But i hope it will be called from async code and  result won't be used.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the `async` keyword, your methods signature, as "seen by the compiler", within the methods's scope is converted:

```
protected async Task Foo()
```

will become

```
protected void Foo();
```

To return a value, with the `async` keyword, you should use this signature:

```
protected async Task<T> Foo()
```

which results in

```
protected T Foo()
```

As for the caller , the signature stays the same.

On `Task`, `Result` is not defined because by its nature it doesn't have a return value from the task. A `Task<T>` on the other hand *has* a `Result`.

So, in order to get an "result", (`Result` is not defined on `Task` (`Wait` is), you should use `Task<T>`, on which `Result` is defined.

In your case you should change the signature to:

```
protected async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WhatEverTypeYouAreReturning> curlRequestAsync()
```

You will now able to get the `Result` or `await` the call if you are in an async scope. The latter is preferred since it will keep your method async which has some benefits regarding to the use of resources.